# How do I change my Active Sound Card on the Fly?

Tags: windows, audio, hardware

I currently have speakers set up both in my office and in my living room, connected to my PC via two sound cards, and would like to switch the set of speakers I'm outputting to on the fly.

Anyone know an application or a windows API call that I can use to change the default sound output device? It is currently a bit of a pain to traverse the existing control panel system.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That topic is covered in depth here [Easily Change or Switch the Default Audio Sound Output in Vista or XP](http://www.raymond.cc/blog/archives/2008/08/26/easily-change-or-switch-the-default-audio-sound-output-in-windows-vista-and-xp/).  Note that sound management was changed in Vista significantly.

On a side note, I believe [SnapStream](http://www.snapstream.com/) is/was working on an application to allo multi-channel sound cards to output to different rooms (sets of speakers) simultaneously.