# Detect if headphones are plugged in or not via VBScript

Tags: vbscript, headphones, audio-device

Is any a way to detect if headphones are plugged in or not via VBScript?

This link doesnt help [Switching current active sound device using VBScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21800476/switching-current-active-sound-device-using-vbscript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use the `Win32_SoundDevice` WMI class.  Here is a sample script that might be a good starting point:

```
strComputer = "."
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")
Set colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_SoundDevice",,48)
For Each objItem in colItems
    Wscript.Echo "Availability: " & objItem.Availability
    Wscript.Echo "Caption: " & objItem.Caption
    Wscript.Echo "Description: " & objItem.Description
    Wscript.Echo "Name: " & objItem.Name
    Wscript.Echo "Status: " & objItem.Status
    Wscript.Echo "StatusInfo: " & objItem.StatusInfo
Next
```

([source](http://www.activexperts.com/admin/scripts/wmi/vbscript/0361/))

I would do some comparison runs before and after plugging in your headphones and go from there.

Comment: just wanted to add a link to the [official documentation for `Win32_SoundDevice`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394463(v=vs.85).aspx)